# Simple chapter title page

Tags: koma-script

The chapter title page should be with a different font, left flush. The examples I could find where for much more complicated solutions and I tried something using the KOMA-book, but I cannot get the name of the chapter in the desired font.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
}

\usepackage[german]{babel}  %scheint 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{CormorantGaramond}   %for the titles

\renewcommand*{\partformat} {\begin{flushleft}
        \Huge\mdseries\rmfamily\titlefont{\partname~\thepart}
        \end{flushleft}}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\begin{flushleft}
                        \Huge\mdseries\rmfamily\titlefont
                        \end{flushleft}}


\begin{document}
        \part{ Philosophie}
        \chapter{  \textit{Vom Schreiben}}
        \chapter{Zwei}
\end{document}
```

and the expected result should be similar to

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code.

- Don't use environments inside `\setkomafont`
- Don't invoke font specific commands in the redefinition of `\partformat`. That's why `\setkomafont` exists.
- `\titlefont` is already defined so you have to choose another name for your font family command
- In my humble opinion it's not a good idea to tweak the formatting  of individual sections. Typographical consistency should be your primary objective.

Here is the output of a revision of your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
}

\usepackage[german]{babel}  %scheint 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\PartFont}{CormorantGaramond}   %for the titles

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\renewcommand*\raggedpart{\raggedright}
\setkomafont{part}{\mdseries\Huge\PartFont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\usekomafont{part}}

\begin{document}

\part{Philosophie}
\chapter{Vom Schreiben}
\chapter{Zwei}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the explanations, which were VERY helpful to tweak the solution further. I am amazed how simple a solution becomes once one understands the philosophy behind it. - I try to get  consistency and use the part style everywhere, no individual tweaks intended!